# Android joda local datetime

Tags: android, jodatime

I have an app that make a web call to our server and retrieves its time. It then compares this time to that on the phone(phone's internal time).

There is a 10 minute tolerance and if this is exceeded then the user is navigated out of the app.

This works fine. The problem i'm having is that the app is being used by a company in a different country, with a different time zone. The user is being kicked out of the app. How can i apply local time functionality to my DateTime object. Our server is in the UK, the customer is in Gibraltar. Thanks in advance.

Below is the code that retrieves the DateTime from our servers

```
 @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                NfcScannerApplication.timeIsCorrect();
                externalTime = result;
                Log.e(TAG, "external time in post execute from service = " + externalTime);


                DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss");
                DateTime externalDateTime = null;

                try{

                externalDateTime= df.parseDateTime(externalTime);


 nfcscannerapplication.setExternalTime(externalDateTime);



            String systemExternalTimeTolerance = appSharedPrefs.getString("180", null);
            Log.e(TAG, " comp opt 180 = " + systemExternalTimeTolerance);
            long toleranceInMillis = Long.parseLong(systemExternalTimeTolerance) * 1000 * 60;
            Log.e(TAG, "toleranceInMillis = " + toleranceInMillis);



            long differenceBetweenTimes = nfcscannerapplication.getInternalTime().getMillis() - 
                 nfcscannerapplication.getExternalTime().getMillis();


            Log.e(TAG, "About to make comparison1 differenceBetweenTimes = " + differenceBetweenTimes);
            if(differenceBetweenTimes > toleranceInMillis){
                NfcScannerApplication.timeIsIncorrect();
                 DateTimeFormatter df4 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy H:mm");
                    String formattedExternalTime2 = df4.print(externalDateTime);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        NfcBaseActivity.this);

                    // set title
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Incorrect Phone Time ");

                    // set dialog message
                    alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Please check your phone's system time. The current date and time is "+formattedExternalTime2 +"\n" + "\n" + "Click Ok to exit app")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                Intent entryActivityintent = new Intent(NfcBaseActivity.this,
                                        EntryActivity.class);
                                entryActivityintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(entryActivityintent);
                                //System.exit(0);
                            }
                          });

                        // create alert dialog
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                        // show it
                        if(NfcScannerApplication.isActivityVisible() == true){
                        alertDialog.show();
                        }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTimeZone ukTime = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London");
            DateTimeZone.setDefault(ukTime);

            DateTime ukinternalTime = new DateTime(nfcscannerapplication.getInternalTime().getMillis());
            //local time
            LocalDateTime localDateTime = ukinternalTime.
                withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault()).toLocalDateTime();




            long differenceBetweenTimes = localDateTime.toDateTime().getMillis() - 
                 nfcscannerapplication.getExternalTime().getMillis();
```